# Stop gecko driver downloads

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, firefox-addon

Any ideas which ff preferences should be modified in order to stop sending requests for GeckoMediaPlugins (we don't use this plugin)?

```
addons.productaddons    INFO    sending request to: https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/3/GMP/47.0.1/20160623154057/WINNT_x86_64-msvc-x64/en-US/release-cck-mozilla-EMEfree/Windows_NT%206.1.1.0%20(x64)/mozilla-EMEfree/1.0/update.xml
```

The time execution of our tests is increased 20 times because of this request.

We use a customer profile for firefox

```
private static void initialiseFirefoxProfile() {

        browser = "Firefox";
        FirefoxBinary fbinary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"));
        fbinary.setTimeout(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(90));
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadDirInUse());
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-download;charset=utf-8, text/plain;charset=utf-8, text/html;charset=utf-8");
        profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
        profile.setPreference("media.gmp-eme-adobe.enabled",false);
        profile.setPreference("media.gmp-manager.cert.checkAttributes",false);
        profile.setPreference("media.gmp-manager.cert.requireBuiltIn",false);
        profile.setPreference("media.gmp-provider.enabled",false);
        profile.setPreference("media.gmp-widevinecdm.enabled",false);
        profile.setPreference("media.gmp.decoder.enabled",false);
        profile.setPreference("media.gmp.trial-create.enabled",false);
        profile.setPreference("extensions.update.enabled",false);
        profile.setPreference("media.eme.enabled",false);
        DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.MARIONETTE, false);
        dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.BINARY, fbinary);
        dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);

    }
```

and **we don't use geckoriver**.
The following preference is a frozen one (so it's already false) -   "extensions.update.enabled": false

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards

Comment: try the preference `"media.eme.enabled": false`

Comment: there's also `"media.gmp-widevinecdm.enabled": false`

Comment: Hi @FlorentB. ,  both preferences are false (I've updated my question) as suggested by you but I'm still getting the requests.

Comment: Use `FirefoxOptions` instead of `FirefoxProfile`.

Comment: FirefoxOptions manage firefox specific settings in a way that geckodriver can understand but we don't use geckodriver (alredy tried FirefoxOptions but it requests geckodriver)

Comment: There's also [`"media.gmp-manager.updateEnabled": false`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/modules/GMPUtils.jsm#136). If it still doesn't work, find the pref holding the url and clear it. It should be `"media.gmp-manager.url": ""` or `"media.gmp-manager.url.override": ""`.

Comment: And if you can't use FirefoxOptions, then set directly the preference in the capabilities. `FirefoxProfile` builds the profile on the drive and sends it as a base64 encoded string in the preferences which is far form efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The auto update of the plugin `OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco` can be disabled in your code with

```
profile.setPreference("media.gmp-gmpopenh264.autoupdate", "false");
```